# C#: No macro defines? How does C# tackle this situation in regards to performance then?

Tags: c#, performance, macros

I have a function that manages language selection.

```
In LanguageSelection.cs

public static class LanguageSelection{
    public enum Language{ English, Chinese, Malay, Tamil, Korean, French, Spanish, Hindi, Arabic, Portugese, Bengali, Russian, Japanese, Javanese };
    private static Language selectedLanguage;
    public static Language SelectedLanguage{
        get{
            return selectedLanguage;
        }
    }
    public static void ChangeLanguage (Language language){
         selectedLanguage = language;
    }
    public static string SelectLanguageString(string inEnglish, string inChinese, string inMalay, string inTamil, string inKorean, string inFrench, string inSpanish, string inHindi, string inArabic, string inPortugese, string inBengali, string inRussian, string inJapanese, string inJavanese){
        switch(selectedLanguage){
        case Language.English:
            return inEnglish;
        case Language.Chinese:
            return inChinese;
        case Language.Malay:
            return inMalay;
        case Language.Tamil:
            return inTamil;
        case Language.Korean:
            return inKorean;
        case Language.French:
            return inFrench;
        case Language.Spanish:
            return inSpanish;
        case Language.Hindi:
            return inHindi;
        case Language.Arabic:
            return inArabic;
        case Language.Portugese:
            return inPortugese;
        case Language.Bengali:
            return inBengali;
        case Language.Russian:
            return inRussian;
        case Language.Japanese:
            return inJapanese;
        case Language.Javanese:
            return inJavanese;
        }
        Debug.LogError("Language specified not in parameter list!");
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Usage of the function:

```
In myApplication.cs

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class myApplication : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private Text myText;
    public int damage;

    void Update(){
        myText.text = LanguageSelection.SelectLanguageString("Hi"+damage+"Hi","早上"+damage+"早上","pagi"+damage+"pagi","காலை"+damage+"காலை","아침"+damage+"아침","matin"+damage+"matin","Mañana"+damage+"Mañana","सुबह"+damage+"सुबह","صباح"+damage+"صباح","manhã"+damage+"manhã","সকাল"+damage+"সকাল","утро"+damage+"утро","朝"+damage+"朝","morning"+damage+"morning");
    }
}
```

Would C# run such that it creates a string for each of the parameters, painfully one character at a time for each string, pass it into the function, and discard the strings not needed? Also note that it is in the Update loop.

If your answer to the previous question is no, could you kindly explain C# handles this? I would like to learn something new today.
If your answer to the previous question is yes, that would be an unreasonable waste of processing power. What alternatives do you think is possible?

Something like this perhaps could stop C# from wasting so much processing power?

```
In LanguageSelection.cs, at the top of the file.

#define MACRO_SELECTLANGUAGESTRING(inEnglish,inChinese,inMalay,inTamil,inKorean,inFrench,inSpanish,inHindi,inArabic,inPortugese,inBengali,inRussian,inJapanese,inJavanese)\
    switch(LanguageSelection.SelectedLanguage){\
        case Language.English:\
            return inEnglish;\
        case Language.Chinese:\
            return inChinese;\
        case Language.Malay:\
            return inMalay;\
        case Language.Tamil:\
            return inTamil;\
        case Language.Korean:\
            return inKorean;\
        case Language.French:\
            return inFrench;\
        case Language.Spanish:\
            return inSpanish;\
        case Language.Hindi:\
            return inHindi;\
        case Language.Arabic:\
            return inArabic;\
        case Language.Portugese:\
            return inPortugese;\
        case Language.Bengali:\
            return inBengali;\
        case Language.Russian:\
            return inRussian;\
        case Language.Japanese:\
            return inJapanese;\
        case Language.Javanese:\
            return inJavanese;\
        }\
        Debug.LogError("Language specified not in parameter list!");\
        return string.Empty;\
    }\
```

And use it as such:

```
In myApplication.cs
myText.text = MACRO_SELECTLANGUAGESTRING("Hi"+damage+"Hi","早上"+damage+"早上","pagi"+damage+"pagi","காலை"+damage+"காலை","아침"+damage+"아침","matin"+damage+"matin","Mañana"+damage+"Mañana","सुबह"+damage+"सुबह","صباح"+damage+"صباح","manhã"+damage+"manhã","সকাল"+damage+"সকাল","утро"+damage+"утро","朝"+damage+"朝","morning"+damage+"morning");
```

I understand C# doesn't allow macro defines like this, so what are you guy's approaches? I would love to hear them.

Finally, requirements.

### Requirements

1. I want to be able to add in hundreds of languages without getting any noticeable impact on performance.
2. I want to be able to type a long sentence in each language without getting any noticeable impact on performance. For example: "An orange is a round reddish-yellow fruit, which comes from a medium-sized tree harvested in the winter, and contains Vitamin C, essential for the vitality of human blood. The current price of oranges is "+calculateCost()+" dollars".
3. I do not want to copy and paste the contents of MACRO_SELECTLANGUAGESTRING into every instance it would have been used, for maintainability reasons.
4. The strings may contain one or several numerical values buried somewhere in the string in which positions of these numerical values may vary depending on language. These numerical values may be updated several times per frame.
5. I want to code in such a way that whenever I add in a new language, I am not required to manually find every instance of language dictionaries which may cause me to miss out on some, and instead I want to offload this to the compiler, and make it give me a "No overload for method 'MACRO_SELECTLANGUAGESTRING' takes 'X' arguments" error for every instance that function is called. (in reply to this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35354147/revisions)

Thank you.

Comment: instead of using long `switch-case`, you could consider using `Dictionary`

Comment: I have been brainstorming for the last 10 mins on how to implement a dictionary to resolve this issue, but I have no idea how, and where to start.

Comment: A dictionary of Lanuage type to what I assume are different versions of "Hi".  Then selecting the desired one and doing the concatenation once.

Comment: @juharr Also, kindly note that the variable "damage" may be changed several times per frame, so I am unable to do the string concatenation just once. Edit: I changed "damage" from private to public.

Comment: @RyanAWE Still you presumable don't have to do all the concatenations for the other languages that way.

Comment: There are patterns for dealing with internationalization for a reason. Try using them. Your proposal doesn't scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using resx as a solution, but still have no idea how to load resx files in Unity.

I have found another solution to my problem using a Unity package someone created.
Link here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-smart-localization-for-unity3d.173837

It's super easy to use. It's the first time I got to learn how to use the SDK in less than 30 minutes. It includes so many languages in its language database and even supports audio, prefabs and other types.

It's the only free localization package in unity's asset store with 4 stars and reviewed by more than 100 people.
I'm not advertising for them. Just posting it here for others looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

General rule of thumb is that if something feels wrong and you can't quite make it right, it's usually not the language but the way you're trying to accomplish it. There are exceptions to every rule, of course, but in this case it looks like you're trying to fit a square peg through a round hole.

The strategy I'd use for what you're doing -- and I really would do this in any language, not just C# -- is to put this stuff into either an external file or embed it in a resource and parse it out into a proper data structure on first use.

As an example (sans parsing):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Language,string>
{
    { Language.English, "Hi{0}Hi" },
    { Language.Chinese, "早上{0}早上" }
};

text = string.Format(dict[selectedLanguage], damage);
```

Comment: Mmm this sounds like a great solution. I will use this and get back here when (if) I encounter any further issues. Thank you!

Comment: I want to code in such a way that whenever I add in a new language, I am not required to manually find every instance of language dictionaries which may cause me to miss out on some, and instead I want to offload this to the compiler, and make it give me a "No overload for method 'MACRO_SELECTLANGUAGESTRING' takes 'X' arguments" error for every instance that function is called. I will add this note into the original post too.

Comment: This is the issue I have with your proposed solution. Does anybody have any alternative solutions that fulfills all these reasonable requirements? I am sure define macros do, but there ain't any in C#. Also, Why can't I add a @ tag?

Comment: If you're parsing the strings from a file, you can have it verify that all languages are present.